# Splash Screen is displaying too fast and then going into the next Java Class

Tags: java, android, android-xml, genymotion

The splash screen is supposed to last 3 seconds but it skipping it almost entirely when the app is run on **Genymotion Emulator** or **Android Studios Emulator** both emulators are running perfectly with other applications. I don't understand?

**SplashScreen.java**

```js
package com.transcendencetech.juliospizzaprototype;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Window;

/**
 * Created by Stormy Forrester on 20/03/2016.
 */
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    int secondsDelayed = 4;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
          SignInActivity.class));
        finish();
      }
    }, secondsDelayed * 3);
  }
}
```

**splash_screen,xml **

Comment: the delay is milliseconds. 4secs are 4000 millsecs

Comment: int secondsDelayed = 4000; and remove the *3

Answer (score 2):

You should multiply your seconds (eg 4) with 1000.

Because you have to give it in milliseconds.

Try changing your code to

```
 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    int secondsDelayed = 4;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
          SignInActivity.class));
        finish();
      }
    }, secondsDelayed * 1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your variable form

```
 int secondsDelayed = 4;
```

to

```
 int secondsDelayed = 4000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried putting the splash screen as window background as per this tutorial: https://medium.com/android-news/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154

and then calling Thread.sleep(2000ms) right before setContentView in OnCreate for the main screen.